# Why am I getting an InvalidCastException when updating entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing an MVC project which is a small part of a big system. We have an ORM service which is created with NTier Entity Framework (it is essentially .Net EF with N Tier support) and this ORM supplies us DataContext. I am struggling with a problem for almost two days and googling is a no go. Here is my update action:

```
IzinTalep original = DataContext.IzinTalep.AsQueryable()
    .Where(p => p.idtIzinTalep == id).FirstOrDefault();

// [...] some changes to entity are made

original.IsApproved = false;//this is the only boolean in the entity

// [...] some other changes to entity

try
{
    DataContext.IzinTalep.Add(original);
    DataContext.SaveChanges();//the InvalidCastException is thrown here
}
catch (Exception e)
{ }
```

The exception details say:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'NTier.Common.Domain.Model.Entity'.
```

If I comment out the `IsApproved` line, everything works like a charm. Unfortunately, this change to the `IsApproved` is utterly significant and i have to make it possible.

Comment: What type is the 'IsApprowed' property?

Comment: Can you show the `IzinTalep` class? Also, you seem to be `Add()`ing the entity again, while your question claims it should be an update. What happens if you remove `DataContext.IzinTalep.Add(original);`?

Comment: Like i said, it is a boolean. I checked twice.

Comment: @CodeCaster it is an auto-generated class with the N-Tier Entity Framework's code generation. I don't have access to it now.

Comment: You appear to have an `IzinTalep` that is an entity and a `DataContext.IzinTalep` that is a `DbSet`. Something smells there. Can you rename the entity class?

Comment: @Colin can you explain why and what you think that will fix? It's perfectly valid to have a collection of Foo named Foo.

Comment: @CodeCaster removed the line, there seems to be no change in the way the code works, yet does not solve my problem. I am checking the DB through SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @CodeCaster fair call. But I would change it if I could because it is confusing. The `Add` smells too and should be giving a different error or adding a duplicate. Also the `.AsQueryable()` should be redundant if `DataContext.IzinTalep` is indeed a `DbSet`. So I'd remove both of those. But I can't say that any of these changes will fix anything, unfortunately.

Comment: What about inside the `SaveChanges` method? Are you triggering any other queries or updates on the database when an `IzinTalep` is approved?

Comment: @Colin the `Add` wasn't adding a duplicate, yet I removed it as suggested. `DataContext.IzinTalep` is an `EntitySet` but i don't know if it is different than a `DbSet`. As to your `AsQueryable` suggestion, if I don't use it, i cannot find any entity as the DataContext is empty. Also, if it's not clear, I am using a remote ORM service. Entity classes and context are supplied by dll's which are also being used by the ORM service.

Comment: @All We're dealing with an n-tier entity framework DataContext here --> if AsQueriable() is used, the query is executed remotely, if AsQueriable() is omitted the query runs against the local in-memory data stored in DataContext

Comment: @All The Add() should be omitted although it doesn't hurt since it doesn't do anything if the entity is already contained in the data context (compared by reference)

Comment: @ChristofSenn thanks, i was trying to say the same thing as you but apparently I couldn't. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old problem of NTier Entity Framework which is fixed in the last version. If you want to use the old version you should done following: In Model folder at NTier.Common.Domain package, change 250th line of ChangeSetExtensions.cs to "as Entity" instead of using typecast as "(Entity)".

Comment: This solution works for the `NTIER_EF` version we use. I'll mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your fault. The reason was an issue in the n-tier entity framework that has been resoved now with release 1.4

To fix the issue in an existing solution simply update the 'NTierEntityFramework.Common' nuget package.
You can do so e.g. using the Package Manager Console updating all packages in use:

PM> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process

PM> Update-Package

Answer (score 0):

If this is what I think this is, then this is what was happening to me

I have a poco object (e.g. Car)
I have a Database that has a Car table
My poco matches the properties of the database exactly.

My EF model was generated from the database and then I had a nice EF datacontext

The problem being that when I ask my datacontext for a Car it gave me a different type of Car object. Essentially I had a Car class (mine) and a DataContext.Car type (the generated code from the model)

So I had a few options here

1) Create a utility function (I called it MapCar) that would take in a Car and return a DataContext.Car (and another that did the opposite)

e.g.

```
Public DataContext.Car MapCar(Car car)
{
     Return new DataContext.Car
     {
         Id = car.Id,
         Make = car.Make,
         etc etc
     };
}


Public Car MapCar(DataContext.Car efCar)
{
     Return new Car
     {
         Id = efCar.Id,
         Make = efCar.Make,
         etc etc
     };
}
```

2) Similar to #1 above and but us the AutoMapper library

3) Use Linq to do the work for you

```
var myCar = DataContext.Cars.AsQueryable()
.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()
.Select(c => new Car {Id=c.Id,Make=c.Make etc etc} );
```

Comment: You can see from the code that OP is operating directly on an entity returned by the context.

Comment: Also, i don't have poco models